# LinkedBlockingQueue and addAll()

Tags: java

If an attempt to add a collection to a blocking queue that exceeds the blocking queue's remaining size, what is supposed to happen? This isn't clear from the documentation I've read so far.

```
     LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> foo = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(3);
        foo.add(1);
        foo.add(2);
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> tenElements = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer(10); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tenElements.add(i);   

        foo.addAll(collectionWith10elements);
```

Comment: I think that the thread providing the elements will block until some element from foo is consumed so that there is space to be inserted.

Comment: Just try and see what happens? Have a look at the source code? Go find the javadoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#add(E)) state that an `IllegalStateException` is thrown if the queue is full:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning `true` upon success and throwing an `IllegalStateException` if no space is currently available.

When you try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l.add(10);
    l.add(20);
    l.add(30);
    l.add(40);
    l.add(50);
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> foo = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(3);
    foo.add(1);
    foo.add(2);
    foo.addAll(l);
}
```

You will get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.addAll(AbstractQueue.java:187)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was confusing add() for put() actually. There is no "blocking" putAll() so this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Elements persisted in the queue should be consumed once the capacity reached, otherwise we will get this Exception :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.addAll(AbstractQueue.java:187)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on my IDE and it got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.addAll(AbstractQueue.java:187)
```

If you want to learn more, go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).